# How can I log to GCP Cloud Logging from the browser

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, logging, browser

I'd like to be able to capture logs in my client-side code which feed back to the GCP cloud logging.

However there doesn't seem to be a client library for (browser) JavaScript. https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries lists various other runtimes (including node.js).

What's the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Did have a look to firebase?

Comment: Yes @guillaumeblaquiere I don't see any easy way to do it via Firebase either.

Comment: Did you try crashlytics? https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics

Comment: No I didn't @guillaumeblaquiere. I had assumed that was only for errors rather than general Observability. I'll take a look.